# Refresh ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have problem to refresh my `ListView` when I use scroll down. We need update my adapter. I don't know how to do it.

#### My Activity:

```
public class VerProyectos extends ActionBarActivity {

    private SearchView buscar;
    int inicio = 0;
    int fin = 10;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //Quitar la barra de titulo
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver_proyectos);
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setTitle("Ver Proyectos");
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffa120")));  


        listaProyectos = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaProyectos);
        //adapterProyectos = new proyectosAdapter(VerProyectos.this, list);
        addProyect(inicio, fin);
        inicio += 10;   

        listaProyectos.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                    long arg3) {

                Intent irAInfoProyecto = new Intent(VerProyectos.this, InfoProyecto.class);
                irAInfoProyecto.putExtra("tituloProyecto", datos[pos].getTitulo());
                irAInfoProyecto.putExtra("descripcionProyecto", datos[pos].getDescripcion());
                irAInfoProyecto.putExtra("totalProyecto", datos[pos].getTotal());
                irAInfoProyecto.putExtra("invertirProyecto", datos[pos].getInvertido());

                startActivity(irAInfoProyecto);
            }
        });

        listaProyectos.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            private int visibleThereshold = 0;
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Realizamos la actualizacion cuando se detenga el Scroll,
                // o sea, este en estado idle

                if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
                            // Si el ultimo elemento + 1 es mayor o igual que el
                            // numero de elementos en la lista menos los que quedan
                            // fuera de la pantalla inicia la carga
                    if (listaProyectos.getLastVisiblePosition() == listaProyectos.getAdapter().getCount() - 1
                            && listaProyectos.getChildAt(listaProyectos.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= listaProyectos.getHeight()){
                                    // Añado a la lista una footer view para indicarle al
                                    // usuario que se estan cargando datos
                        addProyect(inicio, fin);
                        inicio += 10;   

                        //listaProyectos.refreshDrawableState();    
                        //adapterProyectos.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            }
        });



    }

    private void addProyect(final int principio, final int ultimo) {
        final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VerProyectos.this);
        final ConexionBBDD conexion = new ConexionBBDD();
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();        
        pDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog_personalizado);
        final proyectosAdapter adapterProyectos = new proyectosAdapter(VerProyectos.this, list);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {                             
                    datos = conexion.obtenerDatosProyecto(principio, ultimo);

                    if (datos != null){                     
                        for (int i=0 ; i<datos.length; i++){
                            list.add(new datosProyectos(datos[i].getTotal(), datos[i].getInvertido(), datos[i].getDesde(),
                                    datos[i].getTitulo(), datos[i].getDescripcion(), datos[i].getDibujo(), 
                                    Integer.parseInt(datos[i].getTotal()), Integer.parseInt(datos[i].getInvertido())));
                            //adapterProyectos.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }   
                        //listaAux.add(list);
                    }
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {                          
                        public void run() {                     
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                            int pos = listaProyectos.getCount() - 1;
                            // Inicializamos el adapter.
                            listaProyectos.setAdapter(adapterProyectos);



                            //listaProyectos.setSelection((listaProyectos.getCount() -12));
                            listaProyectos.setSelection(pos);

                        }
                    }); 
                }   

        }).start(); 

    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.ver_proyectos, menu);       
         return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent irAMenuInversor = new Intent(this, MenuInversor.class);
        startActivity(irAMenuInversor);
        finish();
    }
}
```

#### My adapter:

```
public class proyectosAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<datosProyectos> {

    public proyectosAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<datosProyectos> datos) { 
        super(context, R.layout.cuadro_proyecto, datos);
        // Guardamos los parámetros en variables de clase.
        this.context = context;
        this.datos = datos;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // En primer lugar "inflamos" una nueva vista, que será la que se
        // mostrará en la celda del ListView. Para ello primero creamos el
        // inflater, y después inflamos la vista.
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cuadro_proyecto, null);

        bar = (ProgressBar) item.findViewById(R.id.progressBar_proyecto);
        titulo = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textCategoria);
        descripcion = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textDescripcion);
        total = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textTotal);
        invertido = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textInvertido);
        desde = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textDesde);     
        imagen = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.list_image_proyecto);

        bar.setMax(datos.get(position).getBarTotal());
        bar.setProgress(datos.get(position).getBarProgreso());
        if (datos.get(position).getBarProgreso() >= datos.get(position).getBarTotal()){
            bar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, Mode.SRC_IN);
        }

        titulo.setText(datos.get(position).getTitulo());
        descripcion.setText(datos.get(position).getDescripcion());
        total.setText(datos.get(position).getTotal());
        invertido.setText(datos.get(position).getInvertido());
        desde.setText(datos.get(position).getDesde());
        imagen.setImageBitmap(datos.get(position).getDibujo());

        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean pull to refresh?

Comment: Hi, sorry my english is a little bad. We need refresh adapter because when I add more items and click on item I loose references of my adapter.

Comment: Just Call notifyDataSetChanged(); method after data updation to your adapter.

Comment: I read about this method but I proved it, but it didn´t work. Where I have put this methos in my code? Could you take my code and put it?

Comment: `final proyectosAdapter adapterProyectos = new proyectosAdapter(VerProyectos.this, list);` You are creating an new adapter using an old `list`. But then you should first fill the list with new data before you are doing that. After that just set the new adapter. But don't you just want to add items to an existing list? Just add to the list in the adapter and then a notify data set changed will do.
 `

Comment: I take data from my database, but it is bigger and I had out of memory. I decided load more items with method scroll down. Now, my problem is when I load more items my adapter lose the position of my listview.

Comment: http://www.tutecentral.com/android-pull-to-refresh/

Comment: Save the position before you set a new adapter. Then restore position.